# Is it possible to revert from dualboot back to uniboot (Windows 7 Starter only)?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, uninstall, ubuntu-netbook

I am on a netbook and got recommended to try Ubuntu. So i am going to run it with Windows 7 Starter still as my OS. But if I decide to go with Ubuntu as my main OS is there any way to go back to Windows 7 Starter if for whatever reason I change my mind?

Sorry if it is a simple, silly question. I am unsure so thought I would ask.

Comment: If you are afraid to change your system irreversible, you can boot ubuntu from a USB-drive or a CD without actually altering your PC/Harddrive. Follow the instructions [HERE](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/help/guide) if you don't know how to start over. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use disk partitions to have both Windows 7 and Ubuntu, this way, if you decide you want to change back to windows, you just need to choose it at startup.

This is called dual boot.

You can find more information on one of these links:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot
- http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2010/10/12/ubuntu-10-10-manual-disk-partitioning-guide/

Answer (score 0):

If you install Ubuntu on a different partition next to win7, you should get the grub menu allowing you to boot into Ubuntu or win7 as long as you don't reformat win7.
If you want to delete grub boot from win7 installation dvd and choose to repair existing windows installation (or something like this).

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a dualboot (Ubuntu+Windows), you can uninstall any system (Ubuntu or Windows) in 1 click via this little tool: [OS-Uninstaller](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller)

[image]